# Doom 3 Project file includes

Tags: windows, visual-studio, include, include-path

I am in the process of cleaning up code and want to minimalize #includes from some source files.

I have been looking over id Softwares Doom 3 source code and have noticed that many files do not include anything, yet still have access to #defines defined in other files.

For example, Timer.h has no #includes what so ever yet has access to the ID_INLINE macro.

I have compared .sln, .vcxproj, .vcxproj.filters, .props files and I am nearly identical with theirs (minus number of files, file names, etc).

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Header files aren't compiled by themselves; they're #included into .cpp files, and the .cpp files are compiled. So it's possible for a header file `X` to reference macros that are defined in some other header file `Y` (that does not include `X`), and when both `Y` and `X` are included (in that specific order) into some source (.cpp) file, then all the references will work out.

In your case, almost certainly what's happening is the file `sys/sys_public.h` is ultimately #included in every file before macros like `ID_INLINE` are referenced. Indeed, if you grep around, you'll see that `sys_public.h` is #included from `precompiled.h`, which is the first header file included in many .cpp files.